# RIA: No property or field X exists in type Y (after using [ExternalReference])

Tags: silverlight, ria, wcf-ria-services, telerik-grid

This is a WCF/RIA issue.

I have entity A with a foreign key to Entity B. I have setup an ExternalReference between A (foreign key) and B (primary key) called 'Name' because they are not in the same DataDomainService.

In my grid I am displaying a property of B and due to the external reference it is called 'Name.Name'  because it is user readable. When I try to sort the 'Name.Name' column I get the error

"System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException: Load operation failed for query 'GetA'. No property or field 'Name' exists in type 'A'"

Conceptually I understand why I'm getting this error but I do not know how to get around it.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.